# Getting the name of the Snapshot from a specific VM?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmware-server, powercli

How can I get the name of the snapshot that the particular machine is using?

I have tried:

```
Get-VM -Name vdix-test-01 | Get-Snapshot
```

but it returns blank..

I am trying to retrieve the **name** of the base image here:
[VMWare Horizon 7 Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yno11.png)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I tried your command on my vcenter and it returns snapshots name correctly.

Comment: I've tried it in my environment and received all snapshots of my VM as well. Alternatively there is a simplier version. Get-Snapshot -VM $VMNAME